# How to properly implement microsoft text to speech in PHP

Tags: php

Am trying to implement microsoft text to speech in php by following the tutorials in the link below.

[Microsoft API Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech)

**here is the API Sample post request**

```
POST /cognitiveservices/v1 HTTP/1.1

X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: raw-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm
Content-Type: application/ssml+xml
Host: westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com
Content-Length: 225
Authorization: Bearer [Base64 access_token]

<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female'
    name='en-US-AriaRUS'>
        Microsoft Speech Service Text-to-Speech API
</voice></speak>
```

I have already obtained my access token.

**Here is my Issue.**  How to I added the text that I will be converted to speech.
I have tried tried this

```
$params = "Hello I need to be converted to Voice";
```

but nothing comes.no error message.

**Here is the entire coding so far**

```
$url = 'https://westus.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1';
$curl = curl_init();
$params = "Hello I need to be converted to Voice";


$myApp_name = 'Text-to-Speech-App';
$header = [
"Authorization: Bearer mytoken-goes-here",
    "Content-Type: application/ssml+xml",
"X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: raw-16khz-16bit-mono-pcm",
"User-Agent: $myApp_name",
"Content-Length:". strlen($params)
];


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

echo $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Try curl_getinfo to get more information regarding the response. Have you tried it outside PHP first? Like in Postman? Just to get used to their API?

Comment: thanks for responding. judging from the API sample request. It seems that I neeed to send data in this format and that is my main problem `<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female'
    name='en-US-AriaRUS'>
        Microsoft Speech Service Text-to-Speech API
</voice></speak>`

Comment: @vuryss  `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`  the curl_info returns error 400 which by API error codes means **invalid request**

Comment: Try to use that in `$params` variable then

Comment: Fill the `$params` variable with the XML as pure string. Like you pasted here. If you want to construct it in more fancy way - you can use some of the PHP XML extensions, but for simple cases like this one - string will do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put any string in the body of an HTTP request. No matter if it's URL encoded, JSON, Binary, XML or something else.

For simple cases like this one - you can create a simple string, containing the XML that you need for your request. Like this:

```
$params = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='en-US'><voice xml:lang='en-US' xml:gender='Female' name='en-US-AriaRUS'>Hello I need to be converted to Voice</voice></speak>";
```

But for more complicated XMLs and to be sure that you're generating valid XML - you can use one of PHP XML libraries like:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Where you can build the XML in a object-oriented way and then convert it to a valid string, making sure there isn't any syntax error.

And the CURL API may be a bit confusing, but the Body of the request goes into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. This is not only for POST url-encoded data.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is having this problem - first you need to get an access token that is then sent with the original code, as a header.

Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech#authentication) in the "How to get an access token" section. That token is only valid for 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you made sure of a few things, like;

1. Using the proper region, i.e if you are converting Persian language you need to make sure you have the correct region in the URL for Persian Language.

**For Example:**
https://uaenorth.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1

The **uaenorth** is specific for middle eastern languages.

2. In your azure account, you need to create a resource for that region. suppose you have created a resource in US and you are trying to transcribe a persian language using keys of a resource created in US, it will not work.

Here's my code, it is not perfect but it works. it might give you the idea.

```
        if($langCode == 'fa'){ //Persian Language in uaenorth region
        $region         = 'uaenorth';
        $key            = 'Key-for-resource-created-in-uaenorth';
        $languageCode   = 'fa-IR'; 
        $voice          = 'fa-IR-DilaraNeural'; 

    }else if($langCode == 'fi'){ //Finnish language in europe region 
        $region         = 'northeurope';
        $key            = 'Key-for-resource-created-in-northeurope';
        $languageCode   = 'fi-FI'; 
        $voice          = 'fi-FI-SelmaNeural';
    }

    $data = "<speak version=\'1.0\' xml:lang=\'$languageCode\'>
                <voice xml:lang=\'$languageCode\' name=\'$voice\'>
                    $content
                </voice>
            </speak>";

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://$region.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($data),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/ssml+xml',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key',
        'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat: audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3'
    ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the curl request mentioned in the first answer does not work you can also use the PHP - Guzzle.

**Here's my code:**

```
    if($langCode == 'fa'){ //Persian Language in uaenorth region
    $region         = 'uaenorth';
    $key            = 'Key-for-resource-created-in-uaenorth';
    $languageCode   = 'fa-IR'; 
    $voice          = 'fa-IR-DilaraNeural'; 

}else if($langCode == 'fi'){ //Finnish language in europe region 
    $region         = 'northeurope';
    $key            = 'Key-for-resource-created-in-northeurope';
    $languageCode   = 'fi-FI'; 
    $voice          = 'fi-FI-SelmaNeural';
}

    $body = "<speak version='1.0' xml:lang='$languageCode'><voice xml:lang='$languageCode' name='$voice'>$content</voice></speak>";

    $client = new Client();
    $headers = [
    'Content-Type' => ' application/ssml+xml',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => $key,
    'X-Microsoft-OutputFormat' => 'audio-16khz-128kbitrate-mono-mp3'
    ];
    $request = new Request('POST', "https://$region.tts.speech.microsoft.com/cognitiveservices/v1", $headers, $body);
    $res = $client->sendAsync($request)->wait();
    $response = $res->getBody();

    // Check if the request was successful
    if ($response !== false) {
        return base64_encode($response);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```